# How to insert data into two table by using one form in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, join

I have made two table a.user_info b.doctor_info. I want to insert username, password, and email in the user_info table and another field goes to the doctor_info table. Also, how can I show and update data from two table data at a time?

Comment: `user_info` and `doctor_info` are related? They have any relations?

Comment: No, I want to make the relations too via migration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are severals ways of inserting data into multiple tables, if you have relationship between user_info and doctor_info table you can use sync method:

```
$user_info->doctorInfo()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
```

Or

You can directly save your related model via parent like this:

```
$user_info->doctorInfo()->save($data);
```